# How to call pop-up modal from another html file to index file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a button to open a form in a Modal. But the Modal is saved in an another .html file. How to call the from that another html file to index.html file with JavaScript.

I can call the Modal from the same file with bootstrap. But don't know how to call it from separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Thing you trying to do is in template engine. Depend of your project you can use eg. [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) for PHP, [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) for node.js etc.

Other simple way to do this is use component in some of js framework. I think the simplest [components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html) you can make in in [Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html)

Anyway, you have to learn something new, expand your webdevelopment knowledge to make it simple.